# Widows Server STFP client (Not Server) with restricted access to a specific folder

Tags: windows, server, sftp, sql-server-2016

I need to install and configure SFTP Client on Windows Server 2012 with restricted access to one folder only. This is to transfer file, the file is being pushed from UNIX server. This means I need something that is command line friendly. The server will have SQL Server 2016.

I have tried cygwin and it seems to be too complicated and heavyweight with tonnes of packages so I gave up on it. I have now downloaded PSFTP, this is quite light and I wonder if anyone have installed this? If yes can you provide a link to the steps in configuring it on Windows Server with restricted access to a specific folder.

How can I make the psftp client on windows server to accept connection for file transfer from UNIX server.I see that I have to run the PSFTP manually on windows server.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [sf] or [su].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to accept connections we need to install full SFTP server like Filezilla, openSSH etc. on to the Windows Server. So I ended up using the PSFTP client with script to pull file and run it via Scheduler at a set timing.